# textbox visibility

Tags: php, html

I have created one html table,each row has checkbox. i want that when i click on checkbox., all the caption in that rows should be displayed with textbox,so that i can edit that.in short i want multiple row edit functionality.

Comment: You would need javascript (recommended in the form of JQuery), I would add a javascript tag to this.

Comment: can you please give me js code for that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [cool JQuery plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) that might suit your needs, check out the [live](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html) [demos](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html).

Hope this helps

Luke

Comment: but i dont want inline edit.I want to have textboxes,for only those rows with checkboxes checked.
other rows should remain as it is.

Comment: dude, check out the documentation, you can specify which elements are editable and what type of editing(textarea etc) they get.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you will need not only PHP, but also a client-side scripting language like JavaScript. But actually I did not understood your question. You want the whole script written, or suggestions how to do it? Please be more specific.

Comment: for one table when i click on any row,fields of that row should be displayed in text box.,so that i can edit it.please give me suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use Jquery to get the parent of the checkbox. Using that parent id get each column in the parent and replace the label with a textbox containing the original text.

On completion of the edit using that parent id repeat the above step, but this time replace the textboxs with labels containing the text of the textboxes.

A far easier way would be to use jqgrid plugin (http://www.trirand.com/blog/) for jquery which already does all this functionality for you.